# Using synchronized on overloaded methods

Tags: java, multithreading

So I'm writing a method that takes a set of arguments and writes them to a log file. However, the type and number of arguments that are passed to the method aren't always the same which made me implement overloaded versions of the method. Additionally, this method is accessed by multiple threads running in parallel. My question is, does using the `synchronized` before each of the overloaded methods control access to the method as a whole or only to each overloaded version of the method? If it's the latter, is there any other way of controlling access to the log file?

Comment: Have you tried it out? I also recommend to read [the oracle tutorial on synchronized methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) (as well as the following chapter about intrinsic locks).

Comment: It's only the overloaded method. Adding `synchronized` to an instance method is equivalent to wrapping the entire method body in `synchronized (this) { ... }`.

Comment: You lock objects not methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the methods are `synchronized` (and you are using the same instance to call them), then you get a mutual exclusion between every method. (Provided that your methods aren't static. If your methods are all static, the same applies but you're synchronizing on the class itself. If you use a mixture of static and non-static methods, well...don't do that.)

But synchronizing on publicly accessible objects (which your logging object has to be) is not a particularly good idea. You're better off doing something like this:

```
public class Logger {
    private final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public void log(String s) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
           //write to log
        }
    }

    public void log(int i) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
           //write to log
        }
    }
 }
```

This way if someone external chooses to synchronize on your `Logger` instance, that won't interfere with the internal behaviour of the class.

Comment: `synchronizing on publicly accessible objects (which your logging object has to be) is not a particularly good idea` why not?

Comment: @Cratylus The explanation is in the last paragraph. Basically if someone has got an instance of your object, they can synchronize on it. If the object itself depends on the same synchronization for correct functioning, you can "break" it this way from the outside. Imagine a thread that synchronizes an unrelated operation that takes 2 minutes with your logger object. That means every other thread that tries to write a log message is blocking for 2 minutes.

Comment: So, do I just synchronize on the object the threads use to call on the logging method? From how I imagine, I create and initialize an object in the class that contains the threads and do something like `synchronize(object)` in each thread. Does that work? That also begs the question as to what happens when the object is unavailable. Since the log needs to contain the exact time at which a certain action occurs, does the message containing the time of action needs to be saved (say a buffer) if the object is unavailable?